# Are there any alternatives to :host /deep/ except viewencapsulation.None?

Tags: angular, append, primeng

I need to restyle an overlaypanel from primeng.The problem is when I append the overlaypanel to body :host /deep/ doesn't work. It works only when I don't append it to the body. Probably, are there any variants to replace appendTo=body? Without appendTo I dont'see my panel at all.

Comment: you should use ::ng-deep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your 'restyle' css at the end of the styles.scss (root). CSS in the root is 'global' css.
Never use deep anymore: [(deprecated) /deep/, >>>, and ::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)

I hope this will solve your problem. If not, please give us more informations.

Comment: That's fine. Please click the solved button at my answer :-)